# MacBook Air M1 battery drain when sleeping

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, apple-silicon

My new Macbook Air(M1 Chip, Big Sur 11.1) uses a lot of the battery during sleep mode I talked with apple support regarding this issue and I have been told to reinstall macOS. I reinstalled macOS and the issue has been left. Again I called them and they told me I should give the laptop to one of MacBook resellers to check the computer. I gave my new MacBook to Macfroum and I received this answer after five days: " The Battery drain somewhat when in sleep mode, but nothing out of the specifications Apple has published. Apple diagnostics report no issue with the battery."  However, Macfroum thinks drain battery 1% percentage every hour is normal!!!. I called Apple support again and they recommended asking Macfroum to reinstall the OS via Apple Configurator 2. Macfroum restored the firmware, erased, and reinstalled the OS via Apple Configurator 2.  I checked again the computer and I had the same issue look at the following picture. All applications were closed and did not install any program on the laptop.  I compare it with my old MacBook Air and the old one just lost 2 % battery with many open applications.  I had the issue from the first day that I bought this new MacBook Air(M1) and it is around two weeks I am trying to fix it and had contact with Apple to fix the issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Check the activity monitor under "Battery" for usage statistics.

Sort by "Energy Impact" & "12Hr Power" tabs to find the app that is using the most energy. If it's an app that you are not running on the foreground, then close those applications.

Also check if any apps are Preventing Sleep by sorting "Preventing Sleep" Tab.

Comment: I added a new picture. I did not install any application on this computer and as you can see there are not apps preventing sleep.